Why were the 2009 Avatar games removed from canon?
Has there ever been an official reason given why the Avatar games that came out in 2009 are no longer considered to be canon? As far as I can tell, none of them conflict with each other, the films or any of the comics

https://www.reddit.com/r/Avatar/comments/16k2iqv/interview_notes_regarding_what_is_canon_to_the/#lightbox

Several of the 2009 games conflict dramatically with the film; https://james-camerons-avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Avatar:The_Mobile_Game#Continuity_Errors / https://james-camerons-avatar.fandom.com/wiki/James_Cameron%27s_Avatar(iOS/Android)#Continuity_Errors

The main 2009 game has a lot of canon continuity problems; https://james-camerons-avatar.fandom.com/wiki/James_Cameron%27s_Avatar:_The_Game#Canon_and_Lore_Contradictions

https://youtu.be/MzSPkF2HxVk?si=u1P4Ho3Rbu6uZ8me - It was marketed as canon, but like all video games and comics, eventually it gets superseded by the actual films and ignored

That list in the reddit post isn't 100% correct. It lists the Tipani clan as being canon, but since the 2009 game is no longer canon, then they are no longer canon either

They make an appearance in Toruk: First Flight, which is considered to be canon. It's also listed on the Avatar website, again, a canon source; https://www.avatar.com/pandorapedia/cuirass-crab
